# content security policy for navigation links

Tags: angular, spring-boot, xss, content-security-policy

In my project, I have backend (spring boot) and frontend (angular). The cybersecurity team wants CSP header in response-headers on every page.

I have provided them CSP header on all my endpoints authenticated or unauthenticated, but they also want it on navigation links which renders only from frontend like '/login'.

So, I have provided them CSP as meta-tag by adding it in index.html. Still, they want it as a response header.

Now, my questions

1: how important it is to have CSP on pages which do not load on the basis of backend interaction?

2: what are the best ways to achieve this?

3: and because our cybersecurity team is adamant, how can I add CSP on response header on these kinds of pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your questions in order:

1. It is still possible to find an XXS in a page that does not communicate with the backend. For example if the attacker can execute arbitrary JavaScript on your login page, they can in theory use this to steal your users passwords. CSP can mitigate these attacks and should therefore be used here.
2. Do you mean CSP meta-tag vs header? If this is the case I would prefer them to be in the header. If an attacker somehow can upload a HTML document and it gets served, they could in theory get around the CSP.
3. This depends on your webserver. If you are using Spring Boot to serve the frontend files you can enable it with spring security as described in the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/exploits/headers.html#servlet-headers-csp):

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // ...
            .headers(headers -> headers
                .contentSecurityPolicy(csp -> csp
                    .policyDirectives("script-src 'self' https://trustedscripts.example.com; object-src https://trustedplugins.example.com; report-uri /csp-report-endpoint/")
                )
            );
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Other webservers have other configuration for this, popular ones are apache or nginx. From my experience there is typically a webserver other than spring boot that serves the frontend files.
If you only serve a JSON REST-API over spring boot, it is actually not necessary to set the CSP in spring boot.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. I apologize, may be I do not have a deeper understanding on this. BTW, I have already used ur solution to add CSP response-header for all my endpoints. But the issue is CSP response header for pages which have not yet communicated with the backend.   Can u elaborate on this? Thanks again.

Comment: How are the frontend pages served to the browser? Do you have a separate webserver running?

Comment: The angular frontend run on its own server on port 4200. It interacts with backend via apis which is a spring boot on port 8080. So they interact as cross domain.

Comment: Okay what webserver is hosting your angular application? Port 4200 seems like the angular dev-server port. Is your angular application running on the dev-server setup in production?

Comment: BTW other popular choices would be nginx or apache.

Comment: your question made me think and i spoke with operations team. It is apache webserver they use. On local a webpack is built-in with angular. This gave me a hint that i can add response header on the apache webserver itself, right?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the response header on the apache webserver!

Comment: Thank u for ur support. I have accepted it as an answer. I request u to please add the above part as well, so it will be of use for somebody like me.